# How to override Equals and GetHashCode with two different combinations of equality

Tags: c#, hashcode, equality

I am creating a collection of my custom class which contains multiple properties. Below is the class.

```
public class OnlineProductHierarchy
{
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public string InsertUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AmendDate { get; set; }
    public string AmendUserId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string TextField { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

In order for two object of my class to be considered equal the `TextField`, `Value` and `Product` must be the same or the `TextField` and `Value` properties must be the same if `IsDefault` is true

So i have two different way to measure equality and if either are true the objects should be considered equal. I am doing it this way so i can use a HashSet when creating the collection to remove duplicates.

Using a normal list and comparing the proepties via LINQ is not an option as i need decent performance.

So far i have this code with checks for equality between my first condition but i am unsure how to amend this to include my second quality condition

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        OnlineProductHierarchy o = obj as OnlineProductHierarchy;

        return o != null && o.Product.ToUpper()
      == this.Product.ToUpper() &&  o.Value.ToUpper() == this.Value.ToUpper()
      && o.TextField.ToUpper() == this.TextField.ToUpper();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Product.ToUpper().GetHashCode() ^ 
        this.TextField.ToUpper().GetHashCode()
      ^ this.Value.ToUpper().GetHashCode();
    }
```

This code now correctly identifies duplicates when adding to a hastset for the `TextField`, `Value` and `Product` rule but how can i add to this to include my second rule?

**EDIT**

With help from the comments and answer it seems doing what i want in a single Equals + GetHashCode method is not possible.

So my alternative solution as suggested by @Lee was to create two HastSets with different IEqualityComparer implementations and if either of these failed when doing the Add i could identify the duplicate records.

Comment: Please bear in mind that Equals and GetHashCode should follow transitive equality, ie. if `a == b` and `b == c`, then `a == c`. You cannot guarantee that, and thus you're going to have big problems. I would recommend finding a different way of doing this.

Comment: If there is no 'natural' equality measure then create implementations of `IEqualityComparer<OnlineProductHierarchy>` and pass them to any collections.

Comment: @Lee Would there be a way to pass two different IEqualityComparer to the same collection? In the constructor for HashSet i only see the option for one. So am i right in assuming i would have to create two different collections and compare the results?

Answer (score 0):

This may do the job, but as @Lasse suggests, you need to be careful:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    OnlineProductHierarchy o = obj as OnlineProductHierarchy;

    if(o == null) return false;

    return (String.Compare(o.Product, this.Product, true) &&
           String.Compare(o.Value, this.Value, true) &&
           String.Compare(o.TextField, this.TextField, true))
           ||
           (o.IsDefault == this.Isdefault &&
           String.Compare(o.Value, this.Value, true) &&
           String.Compare(o.TextField, this.TextField, true));
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    //Not possible using your logic
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as the IsDefault property is only relevant in the second rule. So objects should be considered equal if Product,TextField and Value are the same despite the IsDefault value. So i think this will not reconginse objects as equal when IsDefault is true as well as the other three columns. I may not have been clear in my post

Comment: Then it's not possible to write a `GetHashCode` function.